# UINavigationController push crashes with Unrecognized Selector barStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, unrecognized-selector

Pretty sure this is a memory related issue but its always happening in the same spot, when im pushing a new controller onto the navigation controller stack

```
CurrentActivityViewController *controller = [[CurrentActivityViewController alloc] init];
controller.delegate = self;
[controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The crashes always have a random receiving object but are always preceded by the same stack calls, another fun tidbit this seems to be only happening on 4 and 4s devices running 7.0, can't seem to reproduce on the simulator running on a 3.5inch device, again getting back to memory issues so not going to help much there.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39b42b26 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x32039677 -[_UINavigationPaletteBackground _syncWithBarStyles] + 42
2  UIKit                          0x3203924b -[_UINavigationPaletteBackground updateBackgroundView] + 94
3  UIKit                          0x324e4bd3 +[_UIBackdropView setAllBackdropViewsToGraphicsQuality:] + 458
4  UIKit                          0x31f297b5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 76
5  UIKit                          0x31f296e5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
6  UIKit                          0x31f297d5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 108
7  UIKit                          0x31f296e5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
8  UIKit                          0x31f365c3 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 418
9  UIKit                          0x31f36417 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
10 UIKit                          0x32017d8f -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 978
11 UIKit                          0x320173b3 __101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke_2
12 UIKit                          0x320151b1 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]
13 UIKit                          0x32012e25 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4668
14 roadid                         0x001195b7 __67-[NewActivitySetupViewController activityViewControllerStartTimer:]_block_invoke (NewActivitySetupViewController.m:1372)
```

Thing is it crashes with the most random objects but always with the **barStyle** selector, in my app delegate I am using UIAppearance proxies to set some style stuff on UINavigationController, this is the only spot I am even messing with UINavigationController styling but never specifically **barStyle**

```
if([self iOSIdentifier] == iOSVersion7)
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"titlebar_iOS7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8f],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)]}];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class],[ABNewPersonViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

In the end this seems like a crash in apple internal stuff with uinavigation controller but without being to reproduce this I can't file a bug report, any ideas on where to look for problems?

Comment: For Push ViewCintroller you use this line--->  [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil]; ??

Comment: Post the exact exception description.

Comment: Please post CurrentActivityViewController's init method.

Comment: Let's try create CurrentActivityViewController by ivar

Comment: init is standard template init nothing else is done, crash logs are varying unrecognized selector sent to instance, on anything from `NSData` to `NSArray`,`NSCFString`, and even once `__NSMallocBlock__` so this tells me its a released reference problem but not in my code is the strangest thing, once or twice in uploaded crashes it was a BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1):

If this is a modal view, you need to present it from the current view controller itself, not from its navigation controller

This line...

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

should be...

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Have a look at the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) for more info

Comment: I've presented modals from nav controllers before with no problem. I'm going to change it to this, but with no way to reproduce it is hard to say if this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't push modally to navigationController. If you need to push to navigationController remove modalTransitionStyle and change the pushing method to:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]
```